# stock and cart mixed query

Tags: mysql, cart, stock

i have stock and cart, i want to make a query that shows each user a list of stock-cart

for example if i have 5 apples in stock and he have 3 apples in his cart, then when he search for more apples he should see only 2 (note: i group items by type)

basic table for stock

```
id,type,price,seller,...
1,apple,10,s1
2,apple,10,s2
3,orange,5,s1
3,apple,10,s1
```

assuming he selected 2 apples

for cart:

```
id,type,quantity
1,apple,2
```

so my query will simple select 2 random apples on checkout (yes this is how it should be according to my script).

So when i want to show items from stock again i do:

```
SELECT *,count(*) as counter FROM stock group by type
```

**how i can get counter-(what he have in cart)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select s.type, count(*) - (
  select count(*)
  from cart c
  where c.type=s.type
  # and c.userid = X
  ) as counter
from stock s
group by s.type
having counter > 0
```

Comment: great, but how i can discard rows with quantity 0?

Comment: The `having counter > 0` at the end removes any row that has no stock left